# React-Redux: how can i get store data when component first mounts

Tags: reactjs, redux

I've got api data saved in redux store that I use with a few different components. I am trying to figure out a way to access this store data when a new component is first mounted and the data is already in store.

I can't really pass in as a prop because the components are not children. I've considered triggering a MapStateToProps event but that doesn't seem like the correct way. I could call the api again but that doesn't make sense.

Comment: I don't understand why you can't use props. You should be able to use React Redux's `connect` function to use the redux state as a prop without having the parent component know anything about it. Could you post code so that maybe we can have a better understanding of your problem?

Comment: Maybe I am misinterpretting your question, but isn't this what React lifecycles events were made for? Specifically, anything in `componentDidMount` will run immediately after your component mounts.

Comment: I apologize for this post. Re-checking the process, componentDidMount does indeed contain my data in props. I was making code changes and re-rendering my component page looking for the api data - forgot that I had to start at the beginning of the process and actually make the original api call.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of rendering a component you can use a "smart component" and render it:

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import RPT from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  name: state.user.name
});

class WelcomeMessage extends PureComponent {
  static propTypes = {
    name: RPT.string.isRequired;
  }

  render() {
    const { name } = this.props;
    return (
      <h2>
        {`Welcome, ${name}`}
      </h2>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(WelcomeMessage);
```

So in this way your component will always be connected to your store no matter where is located.

**Recommended lecture:** [Difference between smart and dumb components in React](https://blog.bloomca.me/2017/10/08/difference-between-smart-and-dumb-components.html).

Comment: I am using a class component, not a stateless component and using connect & mapStateToProps. My problem is that mapStateToProps is only triggered on a store change so I don't get my state variable set to store when component is mounted